# How to install g++ by command line in opensuse 13.1

Tags: opensuse, g++

How can I install g++ by command line in Opensuse? I don't want to use YaST.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use Zypper from root shell:

```
zypper in gcc-c++
```